# In stm32f446, if 8 independent DMA channels would be available then How to run 8 DMAs at a time Concurrently?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

If I have 8 independent DMA in cortex m4 and I want to use all DMA channels concurrently at a time. Is that possible to achieve the same without CPU's intervention?

And if is there any problem then what could be the possible problems will arise and how to take care of it?

Currently, I'm using stm32f446 reference manual.

Comment: Hello! It is not quite clear what you are asking nor what have you currently investigated/tried yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.